# Fetch API error on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: firefox, fetch

I am using javascript's fetch API to send a post request. In firefox, it will return an error below. Chrome is okay.

> TypeError: arguments[0] is not a function

Code:

```
url = '/monitor_tasks/create';
params = {
    method: 'post',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRF-Token': 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({patient: '1234'})
};

fetch(url, params);
```

Anybody had the same error?

RESOLVED:
- A 3rd party library caused this issue.

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with that syntax, so without seeing more of the actual/real code, there’s no way anybody here can help you. For example, what makes you conclude the error you cite is caused by that fetch call? What’s the value of the url variable, etc

Comment: updated the code